# Trying to invoke a Hive job on HDInsight from .NET

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm using [this sample](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-content/blob/master/ITPro/Services/hdinsight/RemoteJobExecution.md) in order to run a Hive query from C#. I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> An error occurred while sending the request. 
> -> Unable to connect to the remote server 
>    -> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>       respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>       connected host has failed to respond XXX:563
> ```

Comment: Did you consider using ODBC instead, btw? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/connect-excel-with-hive-odbc/

Comment: @RemusRusanu Yes, but I'd like to write C# code that runs queries and not just see results in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the port number (563) eliminated the error.